# replace items in a string while also confirming format

Tags: c#, string, replace, format

I have a string input in the format of "string#int" and I want to convert it to "string-int" for web friendliness reasons for an api i am using.

To do this I could obviously just replace the single character # with a - using string.replace, but ideally I'd like to do a check that the input (which is user provided by the way) is in the correct format (string#int) while or before converting to the web friendly version with a "-" instead. Essentially I'm wondering if there is a method in C# that I could use to check that this input is in the correct format and convert it to the required result format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way obviously, since the format you request is quite specific. Also, a string can contain anything, also a hastag, `#`, so I guess you need to narrow that down.

You could use regular expressions to check if the string is in the correct format. This would be possible expression:

```
[A-Za-z ]+#[0-9]+
```

Which matches for:

> this is a string#123

Comment: Awesome! I've never tried regular expressions before. Is there a way to make the string check require no spaces? edit: nvm i think i just remove that space after z?

Comment: I ended up going with this followed by inputString.Replace('#','-');

Comment: @user2476545 Yes, just remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in, but you could do the following:

```
var parts = input.Split(new char[] { '#' });

if (parts.Length != 2) incorrect format

int result;
if (!int.TryParse(parts[1], out result) incorrect format

output = String.Join("-", parts);
```

This takes the `input` and splits it on the "#" character. If the result isn't two parts then the string is invalid. You then check that the second part is an integer - if the `TryParse` fails it's not valid. The last step is to rejoin the two parts, but this time with a `-` as the separator.